# I cannot get my ajax to display/function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to ajax. I cannot understand the reason why my code is being neglected by my browser. I am using xampp as my server but it seems to me that the problem has to do with my browser and  XMLHttpRequest. I'm not sure and just want to display my ajax on my browser so as to progress significantly.

Here is my code:

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){

  var xmlHttp;

  if(window.ActiveXObject){

      try{
          xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch(e){
          xmlHttp = false;
      }else{
          try{
              xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }catch(e){
              xmlHttp = false;
          }

      }


  }
  if(!xmlHttp){

      alert('Cant create that object hoss');

  }else{

      return xmlHttp;

  }

}

function process(){

  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

      food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
      xmlHttp.open("GET","index.php?food=" + food,true);
      xml.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
      xmlHttp.send(null);         

  }else{

      setTimeout('process()',1000);

  }

}

function handleServerResponse(){

  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){

      if(xmlHttp.status == 200){

          xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
          xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
          message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
          document.getElementById('underInput').innerHTML = 
          "<span style='color:blue'>" + message + "</span>";
          setTimeout('process()',1000);

      }else{

          alert('Something went wrong!');

      }  


  }

}
```

I really need your help.

Comment: I'm not going to analyze this code. I can tell from the first block that this is an old approach (ciraca 2000) and won't work in any modern browser. Just use a framework (like jQuery) to handle AJAX.

Comment: Do you see any of those `alert` messages? Anything in your browser's console?

Comment: Also, if you're using a modern browser, you may find the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API much easier, eg `fetch('index.php?food=' + food)`

Comment: No I didnt see any alert message. It is as if my html page had nothing linked to it

Comment: Can you show me how I can use the fetch API in my code?@Phil